# Do I need a view for every action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view, controller, action

I have been developing in ASP.NET MVC for a short while. Up to this point, the controller actions have been fairly simple. Each action returns its corresponding view.  However, I recently created an action that I don't necessarily need a page for (the purpose of the action is to work with the database).

My question is - what is the proper thing to do here.  At the end of the method, I return Response.Redirect('\Controller\View'), so I go back to another view.  Is it possible to not have to return any kind of view at the end of an action? What are the best practices here?

Comment: I kind of have the same question.  But may I further ask about your question.  When you say work with the database, what specifically do you mean?  Run an insert statement or something?

Comment: You Could redirect or return an object of something that inherits from ActionResult..that's all I think you could do...but would be interesting to know best practices here..

Comment: Please don't put tags in the title.  Fixed.

Comment: @XstreamINsanity - Yeah. Basically the user clicks "Save Form" on the page and the form is saved and they should just stay on the page (I just some jQuery to display that the form has been saved on a successful POST). I don't really want to redirect the users anywhere per se. Just let them stay on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to redirect a user because they clicked a link then redirect a user.

If your posting with Ajax or another technique and there is no meaningful response change the controller action method to have a return type of void.

Comment: Thanks, jfar! I thought about doing this, but in researching on Google, I got a bit confused about whether this was accepted. From yours, and other answers, it appears that this is okay. (And, yes, it is an Ajax POST.)

Answer (score 1):

If you're posting with AJAX and you don't need to redirect the user or display a new view, you might want to consider returning a string that displays a confirmation message to the user.

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, I use jQuery to display a fadeIn/fadeOut message letting the user know that the save (AKA, the POST) was successful.

Answer (score 0):

I would say, an action should always handle a HTTP request. If it returns a view or redirects to another action, both is possible.

Consider the following:

```
[HttpGet] // Handles only GET requests
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
     // get entity from repository
     // and create edit model
     return View(editModel);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(EntityEditModel editModel)
{
     // if ModelState is valid, save entity
     // and if success redirect to index 
     return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

The first action return a view, the second doesn't (only if the ModelState is not valid, then it re-displays the Edit view). And this is absolutely correct to do (it's even recommended). But both actions handle a HTTP request.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the tilde syntax to provide the full path to the view, as follows:

Specifying a View

```
public ActionResult Index() 
{
ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start
your ASP.NET MVC application.";
return View("~/Views/Example/Index.cshtml");
}
```

When using the tilde syntax, you must supply the file extension of the view because this bypasses the
view engine’s internal lookup mechanism for finding views.